# three.js: how to make 4 colors for material three.circleGeometry or Three.SpriteMaterial? (example below )

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to make  4 colors for material `THREE.CircleGeometry()` or `THREE.SpriteMaterial()`? 
example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve]. Suggestion: use a texture for a mesh with `THREE.CircleGeometry()` or for `THREE.Sprite()`.

Comment: Also please refer to [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/). The [`CircleGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CircleGeometry) and [`CircleBuggerGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry) have `thetaStart` and `thetaEnd` constructor parameters, which define what "sweeps" of the circle should be created.

Comment: thx, i will try tomorrow